# Options for simple phone verification with pin delivery

Tags: multi-factor, phone

My website needs to verify phone numbers in order to ensure that customers claiming a business actually work there. The service calls and gives the customer a pin which they put into the site. Many websites do this, but I can't find a simple site to do it via an API. Lots of people who sell phone password integration (PhoneFactor, Duo), others are too B2B (telesign with their sales people). Others are offshore (OnVerify, Phonoclaim).

Aren't there simple NA-based self-service web2.0 options out there? I loved the look of "called.in" but its not really there...

Comment: Just to clarify,  you want to confirm that the phone number is associated with the site owner or you want to confirm that the number exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Duo Security also provides a [verify API](https://www.duosecurity.com/docs/duoverify) that does exactly this - calls or SMSs a phone to deliver a PIN.  Disclaimer, I am a Duo engineer.

Answer (score 3):

Twilio has an API that would allow you to do something like this. We use Twilio to send SMS-based PINs to customers as a method of two-factor authentication, and so far it's worked perfectly. I'd consider this a "NA-based self-service" option :)